# Как получить строки с фильтрацией по нескольким столбцам и условиям?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Имеется DataFrame следующего формата:

```
AB | CD | FG | GL
12   23  23   67
34   45  45   87
76   87  98   67
```

Забираю строки из него функцией

```
def parse_table(value):
    if value is None:
        return df
    pars = df[df.AB.str.contains('|'.join(value))]
    return pars
```

Возможно ли забирать строки с условием фильтрации по одной или нескольким конкретно заданным колонкам?

Comment: в текущей формулировке - непонятно что вы хотите сделать и что получить в результате. Можете привести пример значений `value`, которые вы хотите искать и результат, который хотите при этом получить?

Comment: в текущем варианте в Value передаю значение ячейки из колонки AB, соответственно если значение 34, будет выведена данная строка "34   45  45   87",
мне нужно переделать для возможности фильтровать по несколько конкретно заданным столбцам, соответственно передавая в функциию несколько условий (value, value1, value2)
где value значение ячейки из AB, value1 из СВ, value2 из GL и если одно или несколько из условий None рассматривал из остальных и фильтровал по ним,

Comment: приведите __в вопросе__ примеры значений для `фильтровать по несколько конкретно заданным столбцам` и результат который вы хотите при этом получить. Фраза `конкретно заданным столбцам` - совершенно не объясняет как именно они заданы! В виде словаря? В виде списка? Как-то по-другому?

Comment: (value, value1, value2) 
где value = 34 из AB
      value1 = 45 из CD
      value2 = 87 из GL
результат,
34   45  45   87

Comment: Вас просят привести уточнения _в вопросе_. Вы можете редактировать свой вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [30]: values = [34, 45, 45]

In [31]: d = dict(zip(df.columns[:len(values)], values))

In [32]: qry = " and ".join(f"{k} == {v}" for k,v in d.items())

In [33]: res = df.query(qry)
```

результат:

```
In [34]: res
Out[34]:
   AB  CD  FG  GL
1  34  45  45  87
```

---

Пошагово:

```
In [35]: d = dict(zip(df.columns[:len(values)], values))

In [36]: d
Out[36]: {'AB': 34, 'CD': 45, 'FG': 45}

In [37]: qry = " and ".join(f"{k} == {v}" for k,v in d.items())

In [38]: qry
Out[38]: 'AB == 34 and CD == 45 and FG == 45'

In [39]: df.query(qry)
Out[39]:
   AB  CD  FG  GL
1  34  45  45  87
```